# Controlled listview scroll in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, carousel

I have a carousel slider and a horizontal listview in my widget tree. They both have same number of images present(i.e length is equal). Attaching a screenshot below of my ui:
[image]

My horizontal listview and carousel slider is reverse(last index item is visible on screen). In ui i have 7 horizontal listview items visible on screen rest are inside the screen. If i change 7 carousel slider nothing should happen, the moment i slide to 8th slider page i want listview to scroll with it..maybe to a offset of item width which is 44.. how can i achieve this? Scroll horizontal listview only when listview item is inside screen...please help me achieve this..i tried `onPageChanged: (int index) { if(_scrollController.position.atEdge) { _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - index * 44.0);}}`
in carousel onpagechange but since my listview is reverse it is hard to achieve. I am scrolling in left direction that too when item is inside screen.. heres my listview.separated:

```
ListView.separated(
    separatorBuilder: (context, builder) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: 2.w,
      );
    },
    itemCount: imagesByCameraIdInter.images!.length,
    key: _listViewKey,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
      // _scrollDown();
      final reversedIndex =
          imagesByCameraIdInter.images!.length - 1 - index;

      return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          ref.read(currentImageProvider.notifier).setCurrentImage(image);
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.w, vertical: 4.h),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.r),
                    border: currentImage.id ==
                            imagesByCameraIdInter.images![reversedIndex].id!
                        ? Border.all(
                            color: Helper.primary,
                            width: 2.w,
                          )
                        : Border.all(width: 2.w, color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.r),
                      border: currentImage.id ==
                              imagesByCameraIdInter
                                  .images![reversedIndex].id!
                          ? Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 0.7.w,
                            )
                          : Border.all(
                              width: 0.6.w, color: Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.r),
                      child: Image.network(
                        imagesByCameraIdInter
                            .images![reversedIndex].urlThumb!,
                        gaplessPlayback: true,
                        width: 44.w,
                        height: 44.h,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                            Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                          return ClipRRect(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/error_image.jpeg',
                              width: 44.w,
                              height: 44.h,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      );
    }),
  ),
```

Comment: Please add your actual code. Otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: added on pagechange of carousel n horizontal listview code @J.S.